# Get the dates between start/end date in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, date, extjs

I am trying to get the range between two dates. This is the code I use:

```
          var startDateStr = Ext.getCmp('startDateFoi').getSubmitValue();
           //console.log(startDateStr); // 10-Mar-2015
          var endDateStr = Ext.getCmp('endDateFoi').getSubmitValue();
           //console.log(endDateStr); // 12-Mar-2015

            allDates = [];

            while (startDateStr <= endDateStr) {
                allDates.push(new Date(startDateStr));
                startDateStr.setDate(startDateStr.getDate() + 1);
            }

            console.log(allDates);
```

What am I missing here? Does the format have to be in some specific type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it after all:
First I made a function:

```
         var ImagedbyDate = function(){ 
           $(document).ready(function(){

        // GET ALL THE DATES BETWEEN TWO SELECTED DAYS AND STORE THEM IN AN ARRAY (allDates[])

             var startDateStr = Ext.getCmp('startDateFoi').getSubmitValue();
             alert(startDateStr);
             var endDateStr = Ext.getCmp('endDateFoi').getSubmitValue();
             alert(endDateStr);

             currentDate = new Date(startDateStr);
             endDate = new Date(endDateStr);
             alert(currentDate);
             allDates = [];

            while (currentDate <= endDate) {
                allDates.push(new Date(currentDate));
                currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
            }
```

Actually I added these two lines:

```
        currentDate = new Date(startDateStr);
        endDate = new Date(endDateStr);
```

This is how my items looks:

```
    {
            region: 'center', 
            title: "Rural Broadband",
            layout: 'fit',
            collapsible: false,
            items: [mappanel] , //mapPanel
            dockedItems: [{ //Toolbar with Actions - Beginn
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [{
                text: 'Current center of the map',
                handler: function(){
                    var c = GeoExt.panel.Map.guess().map.getCenter();
                    Ext.Msg.alert(this.getText(), c.toString());
                    }
                },{
                text: 'See Unassigned Images',
                handler: function(){
                    UnassignedImg();
                    }   
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
                    name: 'startDate',
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    id: 'startDateFoi',
                    format: 'd-M-Y'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'End Date',
                    name: 'startDate',
                    id: 'endDateFoi',
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    format: 'd-M-Y'
                }, ...
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is quite long winded and over complicated, see my answer for a one line solution rather than a loop

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Ext.Date class to handle this: [Ext.Date.diff](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-diff)

```
// calculate the difference in days between two dates
var diff = Ext.Date.diff(date1, date2, 'd'));
```

Or if you want the standard JS version so you know how it works:

[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j8p)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var processRequest = function() {
                var date1 = Ext.getCmp('date1').getValue();
                var date2 = Ext.getCmp('date2').getValue();

                // JS counts it in milliseconds
                var diff = (date2 - date1) / 1000;

                // Number of seconds in one day
                console.log(diff / 86400);
            };

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Choose a future date:',
            width: 300,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                id: 'date1',
                minDate: new Date(),
                handler: function(picker, date) {
                    processRequest();
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                id: 'date2',
                minDate: new Date(),
                handler: function(picker, date) {
                    processRequest();
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```